# problem with return list with custom api format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I return this list by this format from server :

```
{data: Array(6), success: true, status: 0, message: "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد"}
```

data:

```
data: Array(6)
         0: {name: "سیاسی", parentID: 0, categoryParent: null, categories: null, posts: null, …}
         1: {name: "ipouyoiyoi", parentID: 0, categoryParent: null, categories: null, posts: null, …}
         2: {name: "سیاسی", parentID: 0, categoryParent: null, categories: null, posts: null, …}
         3: {name: "ورزشی", parentID: 0, categoryParent: null, categories: null, posts: null, …}
         4: {name: "هنری", parentID: 0, categoryParent: null, categories: null, posts: null, …}
         5: {name: "گردشگری", parentID: 0, categoryParent: null, categories: null, posts: null, …}
message: "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد"
status: 0
success: true
```

now i create a Generic Model:

```
export interface GenericModel<T> {
 data:T;
 isSuccess:boolean;
 statusCode:number;
 message:string;
}
```

and this is my category model:

```
export interface CategoryModel {
id:number;
name:string;
parentId:number;
}
```

i create this field in component:

`listCatModel:CategoryModel[];`

and send a request to service with this ,  and i need to fill my property :

```
  GetMainCat(){
this.categoryService.GetListItem(this.GetAllcatListUrl).subscribe(data=>{
  this.listCatModel=data
});
}
```

and in html i use this code:

```
 <option *ngFor="let item of listCatModel.data" selectedCat="cat.id" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
```

now it show me this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>
> at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AddcategoriesComponent.html:15)
>
> at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23910)
>
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23306)

What is the problem? How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make asynchronous request, and on the initialization time of your component `listCatModel` is undefined. You need to initialize it in component:

```
public listCatModel: CategoryModel[] = [];
```

Moreover, your CategoryModel don't have `data` property and it's an array so **you cant** access it. I think that you wanted to use your generic model here:

```
public listCatModel: GenericModel<CategoryModel>[] = [];
```

Now, We need to fix ***ngFor** inside component.html

```
let item of listCatModel.data // typeof listCatModel is array - wrong

// this should be working
<option *ngFor="let item of listCatModel">
    {{ item.data.name }}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize it in your component with

```
    listCatModel:CategoryModel[] = [];
```

When not initialized, your `listCatModel` will default to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

What Patryk Uszyński said.

plus:

```
listCatModel:CategoryModel[];
```

But the interface CategoryModel has no attribute data.
You probably want to use GenericModel?

like so:

```
listCatModel:GenericModel[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an async operation. Therefore before the `subscribe` callback is fired, your list is `undefined`. Instead of manually subscribing to the observable, let Angular do it for you using `async` pipe. (Of course you need to call `GetMainCat()` before the view is inited)

In component:

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
......

listCatModel: Observable<CategoryModel[]>;

GetMainCat(){
   this.listCatModel = this.categoryService.GetListItem(this.GetAllcatListUrl).pipe(map(response => response.data));
}
```

In template:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of (listCatModel | async)" selectedCat="cat.id" [value]="item.id">
    {{item.name}}
</option>
```

If you call `GetMainCat()` after the view is inited, you will still get `undefined` error. To solve it, you need to check whether `listCatModel` is defined:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="listCatModel">
    <option *ngFor="let item of (listCatModel | async)" selectedCat="cat.id" [value]="item.id">
        {{item.name}}
    </option>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: it show me this error : `Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?`

Comment: You need to import by using: `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';` Edited the answer

Comment: Can you create the project at https://stackblitz.com/ ? It is hard to tell what is going wrong without seeing your actual code.

Comment: i use your code it show me this error : `Type 'Observable<CategoryModel[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'CategoryModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more`

Comment: You also need to change `listCatModel` definiton to `listCatModel: Observable<CategoryModel[]>;` Edited the answer again